# AngularJs ng-cloak Problems on large Pages with CSS display:none

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I’ve been working on a rather complex and large Angular page. Unlike a typical AngularJS SPA style *application* this particular page is just that: a single page with a large amount of data on it that has to be visible all at once. The problem is that when this large page loads it flickers and displays template markup briefly before kicking into its actual content rendering. This is is what the Angular `ng-cloak` is supposed to address, but in this case I had no luck getting it to work properly.

**CSS**

```
<style>
   [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
   display: none !important;
   }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="loadSomething()">Load Something</button>
   <br/>
   <div ng-hide="loaded">
      Loading...
   </div>
   <div ng-show="loaded">
      <p>{{ text }}</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually *use* the class on the thing you're cloaking:

```
<ANY class="ng-cloak"> ... </ANY>
```